# Gravity Forms number fields as total

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Hi I've built a gravity form that was able to add deposit payments per camp registration.

- Camp 1[x]
- Camp2 [x]

Total: 2* 50 = 100   ------> Number Field using calculations

How do I make the number field become a pricing field if only pricing fields are allowed to be used as final payments.

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a Product field to your form and set the "Product Type" to "Calculated" and then include the desired Number fields to the formula setting ([example](http://grab.by/NIac)).

Comment: Thanks!. This helped me alot.

Comment: this will populate its price as the final subtotal. 
If we want to only show as a text what can we do?
I know if we set the amount to `0` its work but i don't want to show an input field there

Comment: You can use this CSS to style a Number field like a Product field: https://gist.github.com/spivurno/0dfe3bc4bcdc4e96b975